# Print tree in a zigzag manner

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x, tree

I want to print a tree in a zigzag manner level-by-level. I'm wondering if there are any logic issues in my code and any further performance improvement ideas by using a smarter algorithm implementation.

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, value):
            self.value = value
            self.left = None
            self.right = None

def zigzagPrint(wq, isLeft):
    if not wq:
        return
    buf = []
    if isLeft == True:
        for i in range(len(wq)):
            buf.append(wq[i].value)
    else:
        for i in range(len(wq)-1, -1, -1):
            buf.append(wq[i].value)
    print buf

def zigzag(root):

    if not root:
        return

    wq = []
    wqTemp=[]
    wq.append(root)
    isLeft = True
    while True:
        zigzagPrint(wq, isLeft)
        isLeft = not isLeft
        while len(wq) > 0:
            node = wq.pop(0)
            if node.left:
                wqTemp.append(node.left)
            if node.right:
                wqTemp.append(node.right)
        # inner while
        wq = wqTemp
        wqTemp = []
        if len(wq) == 0:
            return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n1 = Node(1)
    n21 = Node(2)
    n1.left = n21
    n22 = Node(3)
    n1.right = n22

    n31 = Node(4)
    n32 = Node(5)
    n21.left = n31
    n21.right = n32
    n33 = Node(6)
    n22.right = n33

    n41 = Node(7)
    n42 = Node(8)
    n31.left = n41
    n31.right = n42
    n43 = Node(9)
    n32.right = n43

zigzag(n1)
```

**Expected output**

The tree in the code can be represented as

> ```
>       1
>      / \
>     2   3
>    / \   \
>   4   5   6
>  / \   \
> 7   8   9
> ```

And the associated output is

> ```
> [1]
> [3, 2]
> [4, 5, 6]
> [9, 8, 7]
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use better variable names

Right now, I have no idea what you mean by `wq`. Also, `buf` could be spelled out as `buffer` without loosing anything.

Also, PEP8 recommends `snake_case` for variables and two blank lines between function definitions.

### Better comparisons

You should use the fact that `isLeft` is already a boolean and use `if isLeft:` instead of `if isLeft == True:`

Also, you could use that the empty list evaluates as `False` and save one call to `len`:

```
if len(wq) == 0:
    return

if not wq:
    return
```

### Iterate over object, not its indices

Instead of doing:

```
for i in range(len(wq)):
    buf.append(wq[i].value)
for i in range(len(wq)-1, -1, -1):
    buf.append(wq[i].value)
```

do:

```
for node in wq:
    buf.append(node.value)
for node in wq[::-1]:
    buf.append(node.value)
```

But what you really want is probably:

```
buf  = [x.value for x in wq]
# or
buf = [x.value for x in wq[::-1]]
buf = [x.value for x in reversed(wq)]
```

where the latter is necessary, because `deque` does not support the slice notation.

This already saves a lot of `append` calls and merges them into one assignment. But since these two things are very similar (only the direction changes), we can also write;

```
buffer = iter(wq) if is_left else reversed(wq)
print [node.value for node in buffer]
```

### Use collections.deque

Since you are always popping left, you could use `collections.deque`, where this operation is faster than for a simple list.

```
from collections import deque
...
wq = deque([root])
wq_temp = deque([])
```

### Miscellaneous

For this I think it is better to return as early as possible. Also, use tuple assignment:

```
# inner while
wq = wqTemp
wqTemp = []
if len(wq) == 0:
    return

# inner while
if not wqTemp:
    return
wq, wqTemp = wqTemp, []
```

Even better, you can move the check for the empty list to the condition of the while loop, because initially `wq` is either empty (then the while loop does nothing) or has `root` in it so is not empty.

This

```
wq = []
wqtemp = []
wq.append(root)
```

can be written as:

```
wq, wqtemp = [root], []
```

### Final result

Wrapping everything together:

```
from collections import deque

class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


def zigzag_print(wq, is_left):
    if not wq:
        return
    buffer = iter(wq) if is_left else reversed(wq)
    print [node.value for node in buffer]


def zigzag(root):
    wq, wq_temp = deque([root]), deque([])
    is_left = True
    while wq:
        zigzag_print(wq, is_left)
        is_left = not is_left
        while wq:
            node = wq.popleft()
            if node.left:
                wq_temp.append(node.left)
            if node.right:
                wq_temp.append(node.right)
        wq, wq_temp = wq_temp, deque([])
```

Comment: Thanks Graipher, accept all of your comments and vote up. Besides the coding guideline fixes from your code, it seems the algorithm is the same (logical idea) as mine? I just want to ask if (1) you find any logical errors in my code (2) any performance improvement ideas. Besides your great comments all above. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Graipher, if you could comment on my above question, it will be great.

Comment: Hey @LinMa, thanks for the +1. As I said I didn't have a too close look at the algorithm itself, mainly because I couldn't think of a different way at that moment. However, I full-heartedly agree with what MatthiasEttinger suggested in his answer. In the end, you won't find an algorithm for printing a tree which is better than O(n), because you have to print every element. And his algo is O(n) as far as I can see.

Comment: Thanks Graipher, vote up. For his code, what does`pattern` mean? Thanks.

Comment: BTW, Graipher, your algorithm is also O(n), correct? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa `pattern` is whether to go forward through the children (`iter` just returns an iterator and `reversed` returns an iterator that starts at the back and goes backwards)

Comment: @LinMa Now that you mention it, yeah it should be.

Comment: Thanks Graipher, thanks and vote up. Looked again for the algorithm your wrote and I think we (I mean compare to the algorithm I posted) have the same time complexity, correct? Which is `O(n)`.

Comment: BTW, Graipher, why `buf  = [x.value for x in wq]` is better than
`for node in wq:
    buf.append(node.value)`?

Comment: @LinMa Originally I thought because it was implemented differently (faster), but it is not really. You do save some overhead of the `for` control structure (https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops). You also save the function lookup of `list.append`. It is also a lot easier to read, if it does not get too long and/or nested.

Comment: Thanks Graipher, vote up,  another quick question is, for your method of using iterator`buffer = iter(wq)`, any my original code of using **raw wild** method to print,
`for i in range(len(wq)):
            buf.append(wq[i].value)`, 
wondering what are the advantage using iterator? Thanks.

Comment: First, in python 2.x `range()` will return an actual list, which will take as much memory as the list is long (`xrange()` returns an iterator that does not have this problem), while in python 3.x `range` is what `xrange` is on python 2.x.  And there you can already see the advantage of an iterator: it does not care about the underlying structure, as long as it has a `next()` and `StopIteration` defined. When the alternative to an iterator is an intermediate list, the memory needed for the latter can be saved.

Comment: Nice catch Graipher, mark your reply as answer.

Comment: And vote up and grant 50 bounty points. Appreciate for the help all the time and patience. :)

Answer (score 4):

Building on [@Graipher](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/135258/84718)'s answer, I don't think you need to explicitly maintain the state of the direction of iteration in the `is_left` variable. All you need to do is to alternate between `iter` and `reversed` to traverse your nodes for printing… and alternate indefinitely.

[`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) is exactly meant for that.

You also don't need to `pop` (or `popleft`) items from `wq` since you use an intermediate list and you override `wq` with that intermediate list right after iterating over it. An explicit loop will perform better here:

```
import itertools


class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


def zigzag(root):
    nodes = [root]
    for pattern in itertools.cycle((iter, reversed)):
        # Print current layer
        if not nodes:
           return
        print [node.value for node in pattern(nodes)]

       # Collect children
       children = []
       for node in nodes:
           if node.left:
               children.append(node.left)
           if node.right:
               children.append(node.right)
       nodes = children
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias, appreciate the advice and vote up, not used reverse too much and found it is incredibly useful. Besides your above comments, it seems the algorithm is the same (idea) as mine? I just want to ask if (1) you find any logical errors in my code (2) any performance improvement ideas. Besides your great comments all above. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mathias, if you could comment on my above question, it will be great.

Comment: Hi Mathias, a further question, what is`pattern` in your code? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa It's hard to comment further on the logic (beside adding in a list and popping from the other) as I don't know your exact requirements except what you described in your post. If the code is part of a greater project, knowing more about the why and how could lead to further improvements. For instance I base the solution to produce the actual output, but if it is flexible it might be better to use `str.join` somehow. As for `pattern`, it is alternatively `iter` and `reversed`, meaning going forward, then backward, then forward... when printing the rows.

Comment: Thanks Mathias, vote up for the reply. It is just a standalone exercise for fun problem and not a bigger project code base. It seems both your algorithm and my algorithm are of `O(n)` performance? Any specific performance improvement you think your implementation is better than me (just from performance perspective, I know from coding style and other perspective, there are a lot to learn from your code)? Thanks.